# Creating a cross-reference to the first page of a specific glossary

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries

I'm trying to find a way to create a cross-reference to a particular glossary. I have several glossaries that I refer to in-text, and I would like to be able to link to a specific glossary whenever I refer to it in the text. To be clear, I don't want to link to a specific entry in a glossary, but to the glossary itself. Ideally, the link would take the reader to the first page of the specific glossary I intend.

I suppose I could get around this by cheating and linking to the first entry of the glossary and having it display the name of the glossary instead of the regular entry name, but before I did that I was hoping to find out if there is a general way to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), but it sounds like you're looking for the [`numberedsection` package option](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:pkgopts-sec).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedsection=nameref]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

Reference \nameref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The label generated by the `numberedsection=nameref` option defaults to the glossary label. In the above, the glossary's label is `main`, so it's referenced with `\nameref{main}`.

Numbered glossaries need `numberedsection=autolabel` instead:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

Reference \ref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

In both cases you can use `\pageref` instead for the page number.

*Edit:* All this option does is add `\label{main}` to the start of the glossary after the glossary heading¹ so you can use any of the usual cross-referencing mechanisms. The `hyperref` package provides `\hyperref[`*label*`]{`*text*`}`, so you can also do:

```
\hyperref[main]{link to main glossary}
```

¹It's actually `\label{\glsautoprefix main}}` but `\glsautoprefix` does nothing by default.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was searching for @Nicola Talbot. Is there a way to link to a glossary with \nameref, but have it display something other than the name of the glossary? Similar to the command \glslink{#1}{#2}?

Comment: @user1201 I've edited my answer.